# Multiple search from the database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a search bar that finds values from the database, I wanted the search bar to search values from multiple columns.

Here's what I currently have and is working:

```php
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "SELECT * FROM request WHERE trackingcode LIKE '%".$search."%' ";
```

I've tried:

```php
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "SELECT * FROM request WHERE trackingcode, anothercolumn LIKE '%".$search."%' ";
```

but it didn't work. Am I doing it wrong? (of course lol)

Comment: Use `OR` or `AND`. something like this: `WHERE f1 LIKE '%1%' AND f2 LIKE '%2%`

Comment: trackingcode LIKE '%".$search."%'  AND(OR)  anothercolumn LIKE '%".$search."%'

Comment: You have to concatenate the two columns with the ```OR``` or ````AND``` operator. (You must decide that, but probably OR is correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use two columns in a WHERE clause with a comma, you'll have to use an OR operator for that.
Something like:

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM request WHERE trackingcode LIKE '%".$search."%' OR anothercolumn LIKE '%".$search."%'";
```

Refer to: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try an `OR` condition:

```
$query = "select * from request where trackingcode like '%{$search}%' or anothercolumn like '%{$search}%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR` operator to solve this issue

```
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM request  
          WHERE trackingcode LIKE '%".$search."%' 
             OR anothercolumn LIKE '%".$search."%'";
```